# After click() Selenium does not retrieve new page_source

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code. First loop works fine, then I'm able to get to the second page, but the results printed are the same as the first loop.

First loop works fine

```
url_city = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g189158-Lisbon_Lisbon_District_Central_Portugal.html"

# launch url
url = url_city

# create a new Firefox session
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
driver.get(url)

s_city = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
results = s_city.find(class_="YtrWs")
restaurants = results.find_all("a", class_="Lwqic Cj b")

page_number = s_city.find(class_="pageNum current")["data-page-number"]
print(page_number)
```

after first loop I get the click() to go onto the next page. Note: Tripadvisor does not update the link.

second loop

```
#GO TO NEXT PAGE
python_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.nav.next.rndBtn.ui_button.primary.taLnk[data-page-number][onclick*='STANDARD_PAGINATION']")))
python_button.click()

s_city = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
results = s_city.find(class_="YtrWs")
restaurants = results.find_all("a", class_="Lwqic Cj b")

page_number = s_city.find(class_="pageNum current")["data-page-number"]
print(page_number)
```

Comment: can you please provide the URL for the page you are trying to scrape so I can see the elems on page, and the code within the loop to see what you are iterating on etc?

Comment: hi, I've edited the code post. It's irrelevant what's inside the called function. The output of the page number is 1 in both loops, when it should be 1 and 2, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your code is running too fast and BeautifulSoup grabs the source of the first page before the browser can move to the second page. To fix this, wait for an element on the first page to go stale indicating that we're moving to the second page and then get the source.

```
#GO TO NEXT PAGE
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
python_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.nav.next.rndBtn.ui_button.primary.taLnk[data-page-number][onclick*='STANDARD_PAGINATION']")))
python_button.click()
wait.until(EC.staleness_of(python_button))

s_city = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
...
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked, but when I put in a while loop, some pages are skipped. I've created a new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75770397/selenium-does-not-wait-and-jumps-pages